# What does "mysql -uroot" mean?

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL Maria DB which is installed on a Debian 10 system
I am following a set of instructions on setup of Froxlor Control Panel on a VPS and have run into a problem.
I got the following error:

```
Checking MySQL-root access...   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1524] Plugin 'My company' is not loaded
```

When I go into my server and type `mysql -uroot` I got the following message from the system:

```
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'My company' is not loaded
```

What does `mysql -uroot` actually do and what does this error tell me ?

Comment: You really should ask this question on Server Fault... Also, it's clearly not MySQL error - maybe from Froxlor (I don't know what it is)

Comment: Do I just add "Server Fault" as a tag ?   I am new here.

Comment: Hi @Penge58, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. You might like to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read articles in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). As for Server Fault, you should review the [list of topic-specific sister sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) of Stack Overflow. If you have a question that is not specifically about code, another site may help you reach people better able to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question:

```
mysql -uroot
```

Is the same as:

```
mysql -u root
```

Which is the shorthand for:

```
mysql --user root
```

Which starts up the mysql command line tool and logs in as 'root' mysql user.

Regarding the error you're getting, it appears to be underlying customizations of your mysql server instance, you should check with your hosting provider, as in a normal vanilla instance that wouldn't appear.

In a normal instance, you would see a prompt like that:

```
# mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 41
Server version: 10.3.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

And you would be able to issue SQL instructions on that prompt.

Comment: But I did not write any login name so were does it take the "My Company" from ?

Comment: And does it mean that the user is not created in the database ?

Comment: That appears to be some underlying customization of your hosting provider. You might want to check with them, because a vanilla mysql installation wouldn't have that kind of stuff.

Comment: I have done the installation of the MySQL myself and also the configuration.  So I might have done something wrong then.  I have tried to follow instructions on the net "How to....."

Comment: Ok. Perhaps there's another better howto then, try to rollback that installation, and try another tutorial perhaps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this [document](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-solve-error-1524-hy000-plugin-unix_socket-is-not-loaded-mysql-error-on-debian-ubuntu/?fbclid=IwAR2-QmOgIT6O3idGXUIqnbtmFSTosI5FhaGqFTacLhbkocfLDim0tQwYCb8) to solve my problem: